# UITabBar comes to uinavigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a logout button in a viewcontroller that I have a tabbarmenu, when I press logout I can logout but my tabbarMenu is come to my navigation View controller,

would you please help me to fixed this problem, Thanks in advance,

Comment: @spire I mean when I logout from page with tabbar , tabbar comes in page that I load

Comment: We can't really answer this without some idea of how your viewControllers are laid out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you are in a tab bar controller, and when you log out you want to navigate to your loginViewController. This is happening, but your tab bars are still visible, and you want your tab bars to disappear as you have logged out.

The reason that the tab bars are still visible is because you are not navigating away from your tabBarController. You are navigating *inside* one of the tabs to a new loginController.

If my interpretation of your question is roughly correct, you will find the answer here:

[How to handle UINavigationControllers and UITabBarControllers iOS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400827/how-to-handle-uinavigationcontrollers-and-uitabbarcontrollers-ios-6-1/15454094#15454094)

It shows how to deal with a loginscreen -> tab bar controller, with a logout button on each screen which will properly return you to your loginscreen (note - it doesn't create a *new* login screen, as you are doing here, it more correctly navigates you back to the original login screen).