# Animation doesn't work of back button when I embed navigation bar in tabbarcontroller in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

I used this solution to add navigation bar to a tabbarcontroller : [How to use Navigation Controller inside of UITabBarController with Storyboard on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458948/how-to-use-navigation-controller-inside-of-uitabbarcontroller-with-storyboard-on)

But I find a problem, for exemple, I embed a navigation in the `view A` of tabbarcontroller, after I use `self.navigationController!.pushViewController` to pass `view A` to `view B`, after there is a back button with a arrow in `view B`. The problem is When I click the back button, the animation from `view B` to `view A` disappear... `view B` pass `view A` sudenlly, the animation is `view B` pass `view A` slowly, but the animation doesn't work, why? Thank you

Comment: What you have written on back button event? Or are you using segue or PushViewController?

Comment: I did not write on back button event, because the back button appear automatic after embedding a navigation bar to the `view A`

Comment: I have a similar issue, however I noticed that switching between tabs "fixes" it, i.e. after that the back navigation animation works. Although, if then I call `prevent` -> `dismiss` combination for some other view controller, it breaks again. Really weird issue though.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing. Super strange. Any ideas?

Wait, here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15868170/2121683