# How to preserve TabBar interface when the previous view was from a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uitabbar

Here the basic navigation scheme in my application

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaDtw.jpg

Once I access the first view of the Tabbed View Controller, the TabView button interface is not present, rather only the top navbar with a "back" button. I want the View governed by both controllers. I've seen a lot of posts around here about this but they're all severely outdated and any pages linked to are no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
      NavController-->tabBarController
                               |
                               |
                               |->Item1ViewController
                               |
                               |->Item2ViewController
                               |
                               |->Item3ViewController
```

To this:

```
                      tabBarController
                               |
                               |
                               |-->NavController->Item1ViewController
                               |
                               |-->NavController->Item2ViewController
                               |
                               |-->NavController->Item3ViewController
```

How you manage this part:

```
-->NavController-->ViewController-->TabBarController
```

Depends on what you are aiming to do... is that viewController a loginScreen for example? You have various options such as

```
-->NavController-->ViewController--[modal segue]-->TabBarController

-->TabBarController-->Item1ViewController--[modal segue]-->loginController
```

That's a broader app design issue...

I have related answers here:
[My Tab bar controller disappears after a push segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915930/my-tab-bar-controller-disappears-after-a-push-segue/15916297#15916297)

and here:  [How to handle UINavigationControllers and UITabBarControllers iOS 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400827/how-to-handle-uinavigationcontrollers-and-uitabbarcontrollers-ios-6-1?lq=1)

Comment: Nav->View->Tab is exactly a login screen. I think the key there is your modal suggestion. Thanks for all this insight. I'll play with this and if it works, will accept this as the answer.